# RPM dependencies

Tags: centos7, rpm, specifications, rpmbuild

I'm building my own RPM and I want to specify a specific version of the node.js package as dependency.

I've tried several way to specify it in the .spec file but none of theses works, how should I write it ?

I have tried :

`BuildRequires: nodejs.x86_64 = 2:10.5.0-1nodesource`

also

```
BuildRequires: nodejs = 10.5.0
```

also

```
BuildRequires: node = 10.5.0
```

---

Get the following error building the rpm :

> error: Failed build dependencies:     nodejs.x86_64 =
>   2:10.5.0-1nodesource is needed by ...

---

My building machine is a Centos 7

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BuildRequires: nodejs = 2:10.5.0-1nodesource`

The full version in necessary on the right-hand-side, but specifying `.x86_64` on the left-hand-side was the problem with the first attempt.

You should probably not be specifying the arch, but if you must, it can generally be done like this:

`BuildRequires: nodejs(x86-64) = 2:10.5.0-1nodesource`

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
  BuildRequires: nodejs = 2:10.5.0
```

The 2: stands for epoch, which is rarely used, but this package has it set.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but still get error using `BuildRequires: nodejs=2:10.5.0`, `Requires: nodejs=2:10.5.0`